# Cosmos DB Autopilot throughput distribution on unused partitions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

According to my understanding, if Autopilot is configured the max throughput is 20,000 RU's and I if I have 4 partitions, the max throughput for each partition will be 2000 RU's.

Can someone verify my below assumptions for throughput calculations that will be charged

If 2 partitions have traffic for around 1000 RU's each, the calculated throughput will be 1000 + 1000 +  0 + 0 = 2000 RU's

If one partition alone is hot with 4000 RU's, the calculated throughput will be 4000 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 4000.

If none of the partitions is used 10% of max throughput 2000 RU's will be calculated.

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is how it work. How it actually works is the following:

1. Each partition gets an equals share ( 20.000 RU/s : 4 partition count = 5.000 RU/s )
2. Actual load doesn't matter. Partition can only go up to 5.000 RU/s
3. If you add another 10.000 RU/s each partition will get additional 2.500 RU/s

absolute maximum a partition can go is 10.000 RU/s, no matter how many RU/s are given to the container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data

> Throughput provisioned for a container is divided evenly among
>   physical partitions. A partition key design that doesn't distribute
>   the throughput requests evenly might create "hot" partitions. Hot
>   partitions might result in rate-limiting and in inefficient use of the
>   provisioned throughput, and higher costs.
>
> Unlike logical partitions, physical partitions are an internal
>   implementation of the system. You can't control the size, placement,
>   or count of physical partitions, and you can't control the mapping
>   between logical partitions and physical partitions.

Comment: I am not asking about the maximum throughput. what will be the calculated throughput for pricing at a given hour for the above scenarios?

Comment: you pay not for the actual throughput, you pay for the throughput you provisioned on the container. so you will pay for 20.000 RU/s no matter how much throughput you use.

Comment: What will be the calculations if throughput is configured for Autopilot?

Comment: well, for autopilot it would depend on the load (since it autoscales up to a maximum). so if your maximum is 20.000 RU/s, minimum would be 2.000 RU/s. and then throughput would scale depending on the load. Still keep in mind, that if 1 partition needs to scale to 4.000 RU/s - it would mean you would be paying for 20.000 RU/s